# Can you play multiplayer GameBoy Advance games on the Nintendo DS?

Tags: nintendo-ds, game-boy-advance

Is it possible to play games like Legend of Zelda: Four Swords Adventure with friends on the Nintendo DS system?  Are you able to use the wireless feature to play together with multiple Nintendo DS systems or do you have to use a link cable like on the GameBoy Advance?

Comment: I've always wished that the GBA cart could utilize the DS' wireless as a wireless adapter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not possible to be able to link Game Boy Advance games on the Nintendo DS. Unless the games you want to play have the multiplayer feature that only uses one unit, you can only play them as one player on the DS, as the GBA games are not able to use the DS wireless features and the DS does not have a connector for a link cable.

Comment: Well that stinks!

Comment: For a limited time, there was a DSi/3DS version of Four Swords available in the eShop, but I think it's gone again now.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that you can purchase a wireless adapter for the GBA and see if it would connect with the wireless feature in your DS. I have not tried this yet but I think it might be possible.

Comment: I can confirm that this does *not* work - either the wireless signals are incompatible, or (as pointed out by @alexanderpas three years ago), GBA games are not capable of using the wireless hardware of the DS. Or possibly both.

Comment: Unless you can provide more details on what you are talking about, this is not really an answer.